# Visual editor is not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with the visual editor in Wordpress. It's not working. I have this error:

*ReferenceError: switchEditors is not defined*

I disable all plugins and it still not work.
If I change the theme to Twenty Fifteen it works (but I want to use my theme, not Twenty Fifteen)

I already checked that my theme has the call to *wp_footer() and wp_head() *.

If I use the same theme in localhost, I have no problems

What can be the problem?

The theme is: http://themeforest.net/item/modernize-flexibility-of-wordpress/1264247

The blog is: http://espiralpatrimonio.com/

Regards

Comment: what is the theme name??

Comment: try to use define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false); in your wp-config.php file

Comment: make sure you have wp_head() in your theme https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head

Comment: Still not working :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

The theme has a multimedia library at the bottom of the editor page. The library was unable to load a very high resolution image. This stopped loading the page. So the wp_footer was not been calling and the necessary javascript files was not loaded.

I removed the image and now all works correctly